# Best way to load configurations to microservice docker container

Tags: microservices

I have build a springboot application and containerized it. I have two ways to inject configurations to the service.

1. As part of the code(hard coded) in application.properties file with
   multple profiles and my Dockerfile only accepts one variable for 
   -Dspring.profiles.active=${environment} as part of CMD to start the app container

### exp - applciation.properties:

spring:
  profiles: dev

---

spring:
  profiles: prod

---

2. Load properties file to the host machine running app and inject to
   container while start.

exp: docker run -d --env-file=environment(dev).properties myapp:latest

I would like to know what is the best way industry does to inject properties in an microservice app with advantages and disadvantages.

- Do you keep configurations close to app?
- OR You prefer to  inject it as a dependency while app starts?

My understanding: I prefer configurations closer to container as I can have minimal dependency however a small change will warrant a new build and deploy

The second option has advantage as the app code(image) do not require a change and you can inject the updated configuration with a container restart.

Answer (score 1):

In my company we go to the first solution, however, I am not sure if it is an industry standard or not. The main reason is that it is very unlikely for us to change the configuration after building the docker container.

Also, if you build different containers for different environments, passing `-Dspring.profiles.active=${environment}` parameter to the container run command is not very smart (it is always Prod for the production container). Instead, in `dockerFile`, you can just copy the appropriate `environment.properties`.